# metafor in R - interpreting fsn output

Tags: r, metafor

I'm using the metafor package to conduct a meta-analysis in R, but I'm having issues interpreting fsn function output.  In general, the "Observed significance level" does not appear to match the actual significance level from the provided model.  Toy example given below.

```
#toy example originally from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7766/meta-analysis-in- 
r-using-metafor-package
df <- structure(list(study = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
                                       .Label = c("Foo2000", "Pete2008",
                                                  "Pric2005", "Rota2008", 
                                                  "Sun2003"), 
                                       class = "factor"), 
                     mean1 = c(0.78, 0.74, 0.75, 0.62, 0.68), 
                     sd1 = c(0.05, 0.08, 0.12, 0.05, 0.03), 
                     n1 = c(20L, 30L, 20L, 24L, 10L), 
                     mean2 = c(0.82, 0.72, 0.74, 0.66, 0.68), 
                     sd2 = c(0.07, 0.05, 0.09, 0.03, 0.02), 
                     n2 = c(25L, 19L, 29L, 24L, 10L)), 
                .Names = c("study", "mean1", "sd1", "n1", "mean2", "sd2", "n2"),
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L)) 

library(metafor)
a <- rma(measure = "SMD", m1i = mean1, m2i = mean2, 
         sd1i = sd1, sd2i = sd2, n1i = n1, n2i = n2, 
         method = "REML", data = df)
a
fsn(a$yi, a$vi)
```

Why does the observed significance level (.04) not match the actual significance level (.3061) from the model? And why am I getting a fail-safe N >0 (even though its just 1) when the model results are already not significant?

Thanks for any help. I feel like I used to get "appropriate" fsn (0) in these cases but haven't used the package in a while.

Answer (score 0):

`fsn()` (with the default `type="Rosenthal"` method) uses "Stouffer's method to combine p-values and is described in Rosenthal (1979)" (see `help(fsn)`). That's not what `rma()` uses. So the p-values from these two methods differ. And since the p-value from Stouffer's method is significant (just barely), N > 0.